# Changing Id references contained in Cloned html LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to Clone this LI and then change all references of the ID "d318" to a newID,

```
var curId  = '#d318';
var newId  = '#d322';
$("#myUL").append($(curId).clone().prop('id', newId ));
```

The Above Works, it *clones* and changes LI id to "d322". I am stuck in how to change all the other references of "**318**". As in the "**318**" in the Anchors Id, Anchors Class, and in the paragraph text.
I either fail miserably or I break the DOM

HTML

```
<li id="d318" class="cards__item">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__content cellb">
            <a id="fad0179w318" class="tog" href="http://localhost/foo/fad/318"> //<<< 318 here twice
                <div class="fadw318 fad"></div> //<<< 318 here
            </a>
            <a id="dup0179w318" class="tog" href="http://localhost/foo/dup/318"> //<<< 318 here twice
                <div class="dupw318 dup"></div> //<<< 318 here once
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card__content descr">
            <p class="card__text descr">This is the story of Johnny Rotten (318)</p> //<<< 318 here once
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I was playing with this. Got it to change the id in anchor classes only

```
$(newId+' .card__content.cellb').children().each(function () {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/curId/g, newId) );
});
```

Test DOM by clicking the Anchor

```
$(".tog").on("click",function(e) { 
    alert('inside .tog'); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using CSS wildcard selectors? If you use `"[id*=318]"`, you will able to select all the elements with "318" string in the id; else if you use `"[id^=318]"`, you will able to select all the elements that start with "318" in the id; else if you use `"[id$=318]"`, you will be able to select all the elements that end with "318"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current

```
$(newId+' .card__content.cellb').children().each
```

is iterating only over the children of a `.cellb` - here, that's the `<a>`s, and then you're replacing their innerHTML, but not the attributes of the `<a>`s themselves.

Replace the `318` wherever it appears in the HTML instead:

```js
const curId = '318';
const newId = '322';
const $newLi = $('#d318').clone().prop('id', newId );
$newLi.html($newLi.html().replace(
  new RegExp(curId, 'g'),
  newId
));
$("#myUL").append($newLi);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL">
  <li id="d318" class="cards__item">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__content cellb">
        <a id="fad0179w318" class="tog" href="http://localhost/foo/fad/318"> //<<< 318 here twice
                <div class="fadw318 fad"></div> //<<< 318 here
            </a>
        <a id="dup0179w318" class="tog" href="http://localhost/foo/dup/318"> //<<< 318 here twice
                <div class="dupw318 dup"></div> //<<< 318 here once
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content descr">
        <p class="card__text descr">This is the story of Johnny Rotten (318)</p> //
        <<< 318 here once </div>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you also have an event listener you need to preserve, attach it via event delegation on the `<ul>`:

```js
$('#myUL').on('click', '.tog', function(e) { 
    console.log('inside .tog'); 
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
const curId = '318';
const newId = '322';
const $newLi = $('#d318').clone().prop('id', newId );
$newLi.html($newLi.html().replace(
  new RegExp(curId, 'g'),
  newId
));
$("#myUL").append($newLi);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL">
  <li id="d318" class="cards__item">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__content cellb">
        <a id="fad0179w318" class="tog" href="http://localhost/foo/fad/318"> //<<< 318 here twice
                <div class="fadw318 fad"></div> //<<< 318 here
            </a>
        <a id="dup0179w318" class="tog" href="http://localhost/foo/dup/318"> //<<< 318 here twice
                <div class="dupw318 dup"></div> //<<< 318 here once
            </a>
      </div>
      <div class="card__content descr">
        <p class="card__text descr">This is the story of Johnny Rotten (318)</p> //
        <<< 318 here once </div>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Source Looks good but I think it is breaking the DOM.
When I click on Anchor, this Alert is not coming up.


        $(".tog").on("click",function(e) {
            alert('inside .tog');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

Comment: I duplicated the above with my code in jsfiddle and it works fine. My onclick alert works on cloned object. BUT when I apply it to my localhost test area it does not work. the DOM seems broken, it tries to reload the page
Common causes? How do I even go about debugging this? @CertainPerformance

Comment: I have tried .clone(true) and .clone(true,true), Still not working.
There are no errors on console.
Clicking the anchor on the cloned object .tog click event is not getting fired.

Comment: This is the first time you've mentioned an event listener. Assigning to the `innerHTML` of a container will remove all listeners inside the container, so `.clone(true, true)` won't be enough. While you could attach the listener again, better to use event delegation - see the second snippet in the answer

Comment: Sorry about that @CertainPerformancem I just keep adding to it. This is not for a job, just a pet exercise project I keep adding to... too learn more about php and js, jquery.
Been reading all day, and I did come across something like this but it did not sink in.
Your solution worked. Thanks again. 
But just a natter of time until I break something new!!!